# Issue getting recurring meetings from outlook to excel in vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am working on a macro to get outlook calendar data to excel. For the most part it work, however I am not getting recurring appointments or meetings. I know from [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.IncludeRecurrences) that I need to add the IncludeReferences value. It is in my code but I am still not getting those recurring meetings. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(9) 'olFolderCalendar
NextRow = 2

olFolder.Items.Sort "[Start]"
olFolder.Items.IncludeRecurrences = True

With Sheets("Sheet1") 
    .Range("C1:F1").Value = Array("Project", "Date", "Timespent", "Categories") '"Location", "Categories")
    For Each olApt In olFolder.Items
        --Do Stuff--
    Next olApt
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `Sort` and set `IncludeRecurrences` on two different instances of the `Items` object that know nothing about each other. Store `Items` object in a dedicated variable.

Also keep in mind that `IncludeRecurrences` will only work if you restrict on a range of dates - `Sort` won't work: think of appointments with no end date.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.includerecurrences for an example.

Comment: Setting the instance to an dedicated variable worked, thank you so much!